# Custom 404 not working in my nginx droplet

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-config

I’m am new in nginx and before I user apache web server. So I got to know that .htaccess does not works in nginx, after doing some research I got to know about nginx.conf. When I added the 404 code in http inside server tree and reloaded nothing happens and the default 404 page is returned.

```
error_page 404 /404.html;
location  /404.html {
  internal;
}
```

I even tried doing this in my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default conf, but still no luck, however Im confused where should I put the code, in sites default conf or in the global nginx conf.
Can some one please give me brief on this topic!
Appreciate your help

Comment: You missed out the root. You should add your root directory as well and most importantly "sudo service nginx restart"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `root` directory.

Let's assume the `404.html` file is in `/var/www/html/`:

```
error_page 404 /404.html;
location = /404.html {
    root /var/www/html;
    internal;
}
```

Usually, we would not have to set the root in the new location block since it matches the root in the server block. However, this can be set explicitly for the custom error pages.

And don't forget to **restart** your nginx server to apply the changes.

Comment: My site is in /var/www/html/404.html, and where should I make the change in nginx global conf or the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default conf?

Comment: It depends, I would set it in `sites available` so that each different site could have a different custom 404 page.

Comment: Still not working, I've added that in my sites-available inside server{} and restarted nginx, no luck, any guess why?

Comment: check the file permissions, does the user that executes the nginx server have permissions to access that file? Is selinux enabled in your server?

Comment: Yaa so I checked it, the files have read and write permission but there is not execute as per my knowledge, -rw-r--r--

Comment: The read permission should be enough. Try adding the code to your global conf instead, maybe your `server blocks` are not well configured (sites-available).And restart the web server to check it, as always. Also execute `sudo nginx -t` to check your config files.

Comment: So I need to open server{} and give name, host and them paste the code you gave right?

Comment: Well, if there was no server don't create it, check instead that your server block is not only in the `sites-available` directory but there is a link on the `sites-enabled` to it

Comment: `Step Four: Enable your Server Blocks and Restart Nginx` https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Ok, I'll check and get back, thankyou for your time

Comment: Well, turns out none of my command work. I tried simple command with location and gave that an output, but it did not worked in both global conf and sites available conf, any reason why

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it is fixed. I tried to add the 404 code in site-enabled and it worked perfectly